# Golang rewrite http request body

Tags: http, go, request, interceptor

I'm writing an http interceptor in Golang on the server side. I can read the http request body from `r.Body`. Now If I want to modify the body content, how can I modify the request body before the control is passed to the next interceptor?

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Now I want to modify the request body, and 
    // handle(w, r)
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what type of interceptors get into control and who passes control to these interceptors. And what is "the client"? Your code reading the body _is_ at least "a" client.

Comment: I added some sample code. Essentially I want to modify the response and pass it on to the next processor. I have the same problem on the server side before the http server send back response.

Comment: You read in the whole body, make your modifications and stuff it back into your Request. Something like (pseudocode) `b = ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); b[42] = 99; r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(b))`. Dead simple.

Comment: Thank you so much @Volker. `ioutil.NopCloser` is the thing I was looking for. Would you make it an answer so that I can give you credit?

Comment: In case others hit this same problem: if you change the length of the Body, you also need to update r.Contentlength to a new value. Eg. `newBody := "New Body"; r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(newBody)); r.ContentLength = int64(len(newBody))`

Comment: @Volker You should probably close the original r.Body after ReadAll'ing it

Answer (score 23):

#### `Body io.ReadCloser`

It seems like the only way is to substitute a `Body` with an object appropriate to [`io.ReadCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser) interface. For this purpose you need to construct a `Body` object using any function which returns `io.Reader` object and [`ioutil.NopCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser) to turn the `io.Reader` object to `io.ReadCloser`.

`bytes.NewBufferString`

> NewBufferString creates and initializes a new Buffer using string s as its initial contents. It is intended to prepare a buffer to read an existing string.

`strings.NewReader` *(used in an example below)*

> NewReader returns a new Reader reading from s. It is similar to bytes.NewBufferString but more efficient and read-only.

`ioutil.NopCloser`

> NopCloser returns a ReadCloser with a no-op Close method wrapping the provided Reader r.

```
new_body_content := "New content."
r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(new_body_content))
```

#### Related attributes

But to be clear and not to confuse other parts of the application you need to change `Request` attributes related to `Body` content. Most of the time it is only `ContentLength`:

```
r.ContentLength = int64(len(new_body_content))
```

And in a rare case, when your new content uses different encodings from original `Body`, it could be `TransferEncoding`.